# Queryset inside fk attribute

Tags: django, django-queryset

I need do a advanced query,

My classes

```
class P:

class R: 
    p = fk(P)

class S:
    R = fk(R)
```

I need some like this, from R class:

```
S.objects.filter(r.p = self.p)
```

In other words, all S where P is equal to a given P

I am not Pro with QuerySets

Thanks

Comment: how about `S.objects.filter(R__p=given_P)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a instance of the `p` class in `self.p` then the queryset
`S.objects.filter(r__p=self.p)` would work. Next time put a bit more effort into your question though or people won't want to put effort into an answer.

Comment: Thanks @electrometro this works...and thanks for recommendation